# Calling Azure IoT File Upload from Android KitKat is returning BAD_FORMAT

Tags: azure, android-4.4-kitkat, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to upload a .png file to Azure IoT Hubs, but for some reason I am constantly getting BAD_FORMAT. I am using **com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.14.2** library as I need to using an android device that is quite old (KitKat version).

The code I am using:

```
    public void btnFileUploadOnClick(View v) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
    {
        Log.i("IoT App","Uploading file to IoT Hub...");

        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFileName);
        String fullFileName = text.getText().toString();

        try
        {
            File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(directory, "payments.json");

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            long streamLength = file.length();

            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(fullFileName + " is a directory, please provide a single file name, or use the FileUploadSample to upload directories.");
            }
            else
            {
                client.uploadToBlobAsync("payments", inputStream, streamLength, new FileUploadStatusCallBack(), null);
            }

            Log.i("IoT App","File upload started with success");
            Log.i("IoT App","Waiting for file upload callback with the status...");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("IoT App","Exception while sending event: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected class FileUploadStatusCallBack implements IotHubEventCallback
    {
        public void execute(IotHubStatusCode status, Object context)
        {
            Log.i("IoT App","IoT Hub responded to file upload operation with status " + status.name());
            TextViewControl.log("IoT Hub responded to file upload operation with status " + status.name());
        }
    }
```

I have the file `payments.json` in the device (emulator).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @fitims can you try using a more recent version of the SDK? For eg the latest [com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.23.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/releases/tag/2020-06-12)

Comment: Not really :(. Our device uses KitKat version of Android.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Not sure why on KitKat you can't use a newer version of the IoT SDK? Java device SDK can be used on Android using the API version 17 and higher.

Comment: Do you have any news? Thanks

Comment: Hi @asergaz, yes, I managed to fix the issue. I needed to import a separate library for accessing blob storage. 

Had to add the following to my gradle script:

implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0'

Comment: perfect :)! Please add your comment as the answer to this question so others can learn. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I just needed to import a separate library for accessing blob storage. Had to add the following to my gradle script:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0'
```